# MacBook Pro Won't Boot. No Video. No Chime

Tags: macos, video, startup

I have a 2010ish MacBook Pro that was working fine this morning. I installed a new version of the Dropbox client and rebooted. It now won't boot up. No video, no chime. It does, however, hit the SuperDrive.

Any suggestion how to troubleshoot? I can't get into safe mode or single-user mode or anything.

Comment: Do you have the default HDD or is it a SSD? If it's a HDD can you hear it spin when you hit the power button?

Comment: I'd try resetting the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295)

Comment: It has an SSD. I also noticed when I turned it on in the dark that the loading progress bar shows up very faintly but about ⅓ of the way through the process the video dims to 0 and I can't see anything.

Comment: I tried resetting the SMC by making sure the computer was off and then using ctrl+option+shift+power but there is no flash of the power connector and no visible or audible confirmation. I then powered it on and it still behaves the same. No boot sequence.